# Tkinter: all radio buttons are selected

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: screenshot of popup window showing most radiobuttons pre-selected]

Why in this code when clicking a button when a new window opens, all the radio buttons are selected?

```
class CodeButton:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.btn = Button(root, text="Code",width=20, height=1,bg="white", fg="black")
        self.btn.bind("<Button-1>", make_code_window)
        self.btn.pack() 


def make_code_window(event):
    new_root = Toplevel()
    new_root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
    var = IntVar()
    var.set(0)
    for i in range(8):
        Radiobutton(new_root, text=str(i), variable=var, value=i).pack()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(width=400, height=250)
    CodeButton(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: And how to avoid this?

Comment: @abccd: that is an incorrect assesment. With radiobuttons you are _supposed_ to use one variable. That's what makes them behave like a radiobutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Following-up on the discussion we were having in the comments section of my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700864/355230).*)

Yes, passing the `IntVar` as an argument to the event handler function **is** a little tricky—in fact it's sometimes called [***The extra arguments trick***](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html). `;-)`

Here's an example of applying it to your code:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    from Tkinter import *


class CodeButton:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.btn = Button(root, text="Code",width=20, height=1,bg="white", fg="black")
        self.btn.bind("<Button-1>",
                      # Extra Arguments Trick
                      lambda event, var=root.var: make_code_window(event, var))
        self.btn.pack()


def make_code_window(event, var):  # note added "var" argument
    new_root = Toplevel()
    new_root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
    var.set(-99)  # deselect by using value not associated with any RadioButtons
    for i in range(8):
        Radiobutton(new_root, text=str(i), variable=var, value=i).pack()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(width=400, height=250)
    root.var = IntVar()  # create it here to give access to it in the rest of your code
    CodeButton(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's got something to do with storing the `IntVar` in a local variable in the function that will be discarded as soon as the `make_code_window()` function returns. You can fix the problem by making the `IntVar` an attribute of the `new_root` window widget, so it will exist at least as long as the widget using it does.

The code in your example isn't very realistic in the sense that typically one would want to use the current value of the `IntVar` for something somewhere else in the Python code, but that wouldn't be possible since it's only stored temporarily in local variable which exists only during the execution of the function that created it.

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    from Tkinter import *

class CodeButton:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.btn = Button(root, text="Code",width=20, height=1,bg="white", fg="black")
        self.btn.bind("<Button-1>", make_code_window)
        self.btn.pack()


def make_code_window(event):
    new_root = Toplevel()
    new_root.minsize(width=300, height=300)
    var = new_root.var = IntVar()  # changed
    var.set(0)
    for i in range(8):
        Radiobutton(new_root, text=str(i), variable=var, value=i).pack()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(width=400, height=250)
    CodeButton(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I am just a student and trying create gui for my project

Comment: And what a good way to save the value of a variable not locally in this situation?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to make the `IntVar` a global variable, if that doesn't bother you. A better approach that avoided using a global variable would be somewhat more complicated—which is why many folks don't bother. Perhaps I post another answer...

Comment: I tried to pass the variable along with the event, but it was not so easy. For the first time I work with GUI